# Saving to CSV gets failed if XLS file contains huge data

Tags: php, csv, type-conversion, xls

I have written a script that convert the .xls file to .csv file in PHP. The script is working perfectly fine if .xls file contains around ~ 80K (in term of rows) Records but when Records exceed upto 4LACS (HUGE DATA) then script doesnot work at all and no error message is being displayed and screen  remains white. Kindly let me know how can I make my script work in a way that no matter how huge the data in .xls file script should  work fine no matter how much time it takes.

Also, I did following modification to my php.config file but it didnot work out for me. Thanks,

```
set_time_limit = 0

max_execution_time = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing the size of the memory_limit php setting also

Comment: Ummm its being set to 128M and the file path i gave was of 25M. So isn't it right?

Comment: It had to do exactly with `memory_limit` allocation figured it out thanks

Comment: Cool. Even though the file is 25M on the hard disk, your script can easily use more than that to represent it in RAM.